# Different operations in different databases

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle-10g, explain

So I have just executed `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` on the same query in two databases that I've been told are identical in every regard except for slight variations in data amount.

And the result of it seems quite odd to me. I would expect the results to be the same, but they are extremely different and I can't really explain why.

```
+---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+----+-------+-----------+---------+
|      TIMESTAMP      |    OPERATION     |    OPTIONS     | PARENT_ID |  OBJECT_TYPE   | OPTIMIZER | SEARCH_COLUMNS | ID | COST  | CPU_COST  | IO_COST |
+---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+----+-------+-----------+---------+
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | SELECT STATEMENT |                |           |                | ALL_ROWS  |                |  0 | 21695 | 231695248 |   21675 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | NESTED LOOPS     |                |         0 |                |           |                |  1 | 21695 | 231695248 |   21675 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | NESTED LOOPS     |                |         1 |                |           |                |  2 | 16754 | 190036107 |   16737 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | HASH JOIN        |                |         2 |                |           |                |  3 | 11812 | 149413947 |   11799 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           |         3 | TABLE          | ANALYZED  |                |  4 |     2 |     97287 |       2 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | HASH JOIN        |                |         3 |                |           |                |  5 | 11809 | 141361365 |   11797 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           |         5 | TABLE          | ANALYZED  |                |  6 |     3 |    583979 |       3 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | NESTED LOOPS     |                |         5 |                |           |                |  7 | 11806 | 132567541 |   11794 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           |         7 | TABLE          | ANALYZED  |                |  8 |   410 |  37982109 |     407 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | TABLE ACCESS     | BY INDEX ROWID |         7 | TABLE          | ANALYZED  |                |  9 |     1 |      4153 |       1 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | INDEX            | UNIQUE SCAN    |         9 | INDEX (UNIQUE) | ANALYZED  |              1 | 10 |     1 |      2255 |       1 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | TABLE ACCESS     | BY INDEX ROWID |         2 | TABLE          | ANALYZED  |                | 11 |     1 |      4113 |       1 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | INDEX            | UNIQUE SCAN    |        11 | INDEX (UNIQUE) | ANALYZED  |              1 | 12 |     1 |      2255 |       1 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | TABLE ACCESS     | BY INDEX ROWID |         1 | TABLE          | ANALYZED  |                | 13 |     1 |      4218 |       1 |
| 2018-11-29 12:48:03 | INDEX            | UNIQUE SCAN    |        13 | INDEX (UNIQUE) | ANALYZED  |              1 | 14 |     1 |      2255 |       1 |
+---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+----+-------+-----------+---------+

+---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----+-------+-------------+---------+
|      TIMESTAMP      |    OPERATION     |    OPTIONS     | PARENT_ID | OBJECT_TYPE | OPTIMIZER | SEARCH_COLUMNS | ID | COST  |  CPU_COST   | IO_COST |
+---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----+-------+-------------+---------+
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | SELECT STATEMENT |                |           |             | ALL_ROWS  |                |  0 | 65196 | 30910863742 |   62465 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | HASH JOIN        |                |         0 |             |           |                |  1 | 65196 | 30910863742 |   62465 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           |         1 | TABLE       | ANALYZED  |                |  2 |   387 |   154265956 |     373 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | HASH JOIN        |                |         1 |             |           |                |  3 | 63669 | 30387250445 |   60984 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | HASH JOIN        |                |         3 |             |           |                |  4 |     5 |     6322900 |       4 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | TABLE ACCESS     | BY INDEX ROWID |         4 | TABLE       | ANALYZED  |                |  5 |     1 |        5926 |       1 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | INDEX            | RANGE SCAN     |         5 | INDEX       | ANALYZED  |              1 |  6 |     1 |        2080 |       1 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | TABLE ACCESS     | FULL           |         4 | TABLE       | ANALYZED  |                |  7 |     3 |      474779 |       3 |
| 2018-11-30 13:06:47 | INDEX            | FAST FULL SCAN |         3 | INDEX       | ANALYZED  |                |  8 | 62909 | 21831787651 |   60980 |
+---------------------+------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------+----+-------+-------------+---------+
```

extremely different, and of course one is quick and the other one is slow.
So what could be causing this?

Oh, and they are both oracle 10g databases.

The sizes of the tables are:

```
+-------+------------+
| TABLE |   count    |
+-------+------------+
| A     | 90,384,025 |
| B     |     22,687 |
| C     |        257 |
| D     |       1851 |
+-------+------------+

+-------+------------+
| TABLE |   count    |
+-------+------------+
| A     | 90,475,901 |
| B     |    223,714 |
| C     |        257 |
| D     |       1851 |
+-------+------------+
```

I rewrote the statement without the `B` column, but I get the same issue

Comment: Can you confirm that the table structures are the same between both DBs -- especially with regards to constraints and indexes? How close are the row-counts between the two DBs?

Comment: The structure, constraint and index are the same... give me a moment to check row counts

Comment: You "were told they are identical in every way" but did you confirm it for yourself? As Dr. House says, "everyone lies".  "in every way" means a lot more than just schema structure. Look at actual segment stats, look at init parms that influence optimizer behavior. Even small differences in stats could be 'edge conditions' that cause differences in execution plan.

Comment: You need to look at statistics, and check how they were collected (and when) on the "quick" database. You can either update them on the "slow" database, or copy the statistics from one DB to another. `DBMS_STATS` is probably the answer to this though. If you're a DBA, or intend on being one, you need to learn this stuff

Comment: My job often involves proving the opposite of what "I've been told" by DBAs and developers. Database/table/index structure, constraint status, data content and distribution, hardware platform and resources, operating system, database versions and patches, database parameters, system statistics, object statistics, regional settings. Just the first things that come into my mind what to compare, when we are talking about "identical". After all that, if we are that desperate, we have the opportunity of tracing the optimizer. So this far, this question is just the tip of the iceberg.